# What is the behavior of a defaulted default constructor with in-class initialization?

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose the following:

```
class foo
{
public:
  foo() = default;

private:
  std::string m_str = "Hello";
};
```

I am not able to find any documentation on cppreference.com or the C++11 draft that explains what the default constructor will do to m_str here. My natural assumption is that the compiler is smart enough to not initialize `m_str` in the defaulted constructor if it has already been initialized in-class, but maybe I'm wrong.

Can anyone explain the initialization behavior here? Any guarantees or is this unspecified?

Comment: You mean will pick-up the initializer from the class.

Comment: cppreference explains it on the same page where it talks about in-class initializers: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is well defined and specified in [class.ctor]/5:

> [...] The implicitly-defined default constructor performs the set of initializations of the class that would be performed by a user-written default constructor for that class with no ctor-initializer (12.6.2) and an empty compound-statement. [...]

So the defaulted constructor performs the same action as:

```
foo() {}
```

This in turn applies the brace-or-equal initializer to each data member as appropriate (cf. [class.base.init]/8).

Comment: @KerrekSB Google can't help me with that one!

Comment: "empty compound-statement" means value-initialization, correct?

Comment: @void.pointer He must have meant "I Added that Statement To Improve My Post".
Also an empty compound statement only means your constructor does nothing after allocation and initialisation steps, the type of initialisation(value/default/zero...) depends on how you create your instance not on the constructor's code :)

Comment: @Drax: No, it was supposed to say "I already said that in my post" :-) I was looking up the reference just as dyp posted the comment.

Comment: @void.pointer: It means "empty function body", just expressed in terms of the grammar.

Comment: Can't we all just speak English?

Comment: @void.pointer: You come to this site, on this day of my daughter's wedding, wanting to discuss the finer points of C++ grammatical productions, and you want us to speak English?!

Comment: +KerrekSB Shame on you for browsing SO on such an important day ;) Also I expect us to discuss these things with well-known and accepted acronyms and terminology, not some self-invented acronyms. In any case, it's evident by the earlier comments the harm and confusion these things cause. Keep it simple!

Answer (score 4):

The form of initialization you are using for `m_str` is called *brace-or-equal-initializer* by the standard.

In the first paragraph under **Intializers**, the standard states:

> **8.5 Intializers**
>
> 1 A declarator can specify an initial value for the identifier being declared. The identifier designates a variable being initialized. The process of initialization described in the remainder of 8.5 applies also to initializations specified by other syntactic contexts, such as the initialization of function parameters with argumet expressions (5.2.2) or the initialization of return values (6.6.3).
>
> ```
>         initializer:
>             brace-or-equal-initializer
>             ( expression-list )
>         brace-or-equal-initializer:
>             = initializer-clause
>             braced-init-list
> ```

And in the section on class members...

> **9.2 Class members**
>
> 5 A member can be initialized using a brace-or-equal-initializer.

And in the section on initializing bases and members...

> **12.6.2 Initializing bases and members**
>
> 8 In a non-delegating constructor, if a given non-static data member or base class is not designated by a mem-initializer-id (including the case where there is no mem-initializer-list because the constructor has no ctor-initializer) and the entity is not a virtual base class of an abstract class (10.4), then
>
> — if the entity is a non-static data member that has a brace-or-equal-initializer, the entity is initializedas specified in 8.5

Coming to your class,

```
foo() = default;
```

is equivalent to:

```
foo(){}
```

When a default constructor with no member initializer list is used, the member data are default initialized. In the default initialization process, for members that have a *brace-or-equal-initializer*, that form is used to initialize them. In your case,

```
foo(){}
```

is equivalent to:

```
foo() : m_str("Hello") {}
```

Comment: Pedantic remark: I think the NSDMI performs copy-initialization in this case, whereas `m_str("Hello")` performs direct-initialization.

Comment: @dyp can you elaborate?

Comment: @dyp As a sort of follow-up and still related to my original question: When a brace-or-equal initialized member is not specified in a constructor, it is "copy-initialized". Does this imply that it was first constructed and now being copied? That seems inefficient.

Comment: @void.pointer copy-initialization and direct-initialization are specified in [dcl.init]/17. If you use braces for the NSDMI, you'll get list-initialization (either direct-list-init or copy-list-init).

Comment: @dyp Still not clear. I was asking about why the term copy-initialization is used. This to me means 2 phase initialization (initial default construction and then copy construction).

Comment: The term *copy-initialization* is defined in [dcl.init]/15. Are you asking why it was named "copy-initialization" or what copy-initialization does?

Comment: @dyp Neither. What I'm asking is: copy-initialization requires an already constructed object, right? Does this mean that effectively this is happening? `std::string unnamed_temp("hello"); m_str(unnamed_temp) /*<-- in mem init list*/` ?

Comment: @void.pointer copy-initialization does not *always* create a temporary and initializes the target variable with it. But in this case, it does (for details, see [dcl.init]/15). However, since the addition of move semantics, the temporary is *moved* into the target. But this move, and the copy that was performed in C++98, can be elided by the compiler. So it typically is not less efficient; however it requires an accessible copy/move constructor, and an implicit conversion.

Comment: @dyp Thanks. I find it odd, that at compile time it wouldn't simply "move" the brace-or-equal init value between the compiler generated `(...)` in the mem init list of the constructors that do not specify it. The semantic requirements imposed on objects using brace-or-equal initialization as well as the *potential* runtime implications make it not as desirable and outweighs its perceived purpose (i.e. syntactic sugar).

Comment: @void.pointer It's consistent with the semantics of initialization in namespace or block scope. You can use `std::string mstr{"Hello"};` for direct-initialization (also as an NSDMI).

Comment: @dyp There is no normal syntax to copy initialize an object from the mem initializer list, so this is only something that happens when doing brace-or-equal init? So `std::string m_str = "hello"` doesn't translate to `foo() : m_str("hello") {}`, but instead something akin to `foo() : m_str = "hello" {}` (even though that is not valid syntax)?

Comment: @void.pointer Indeed; the rules for the initialization of a data member with brace-or-equal-initializer but no mem-initializer are the same rules as for initialization of local variables. The only restriction, as you noted, is that you cannot use *direct-initialization* syntactically: `std::string m_str("hello");` is forbidden as an NSDMI.